# ESRI shape curves specification

Tags: shapefile, geometry, file-geodatabase-api

The documentation for ESRI's File Geodatabase API (downloadable from http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/) says regarding its MultiPartShapeBuffer Class:

> These functions provide access to the shape buffer. Consult the
>   *extended shapefile format document* for the buffer layout.

I found the "ESRI Shapefile Technical Description" here: https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf, but it doesn't describe curves and some of the other geometry that a file geodatabase can contain.

Where can I can I find the "extended shapefile format document" to which they are referring, or another source that contains byte by byte buffer layouts for these additional geometry types?

Comment: Every FGBAPI download includes that PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The document they are referring to, the "extended shapefile format document", comes with the API when you download it. Specifically, when you unzip the download, it is located at \doc\html\extended_shape_buffer_format.pdf.

Comment: This isn't an answer, so you should use the Edit button under your question and include this information as an edit to your question

Comment: I think this answer has been misread.  My reading of the question is that its asker had determined that they needed to consult this PDF file and thought that the only place to download it required a password.  @Vince pointed out in a comment that the asker would already have it within the File GDB API download, and the asker then posted this information as a self-answer.  I think the StephenLead edit to the question should be rolled back, and then the question can be edited to make what was being asked clearer.

Comment: My comment published seconds after the self-answer, which I interpreted as an "oops, nevermind". I think the edit should be rolled back *and* the question closed as not reproducible.

Comment: The edits to my original question have completely changed its meaning.  I simply wanted to know where to find the document to which the main documentation for the API was referring. I cited a similar document I had found on the web, but pointed out that it didn't cover "curves." The question as it now stands incorporates the answer!

Comment: @Vince, yes, it was kind of a "never mind", but I thought others might be confused as I was, so I answered my own question.  If that wasn't the right course of action, I apologize.